# Coverity memccpy issue

Tags: coverity

Here is the code snippet

```
typedef struct
{
   unsigned char L2maclegacyString2[14];
}L2macLegacyLogPayload;

L2macLegacyLogPayload* _lData_=(L2macLegacyLogPayload*)buffData; 
memccpy(_lData_->L2maclegacyString2,"RACH-RM-Exec",'\0',sizeof(_lData_->L2maclegacyString2));
```

CID 138514 (#2 of 3): Out-of-bounds access (OVERRUN)
10. overrun-buffer-arg: Overrunning array "RACH-RM-Exec" of 13 bytes by passing it to a function which 
accesses it at byte offset 13 using argument 14U.

Looks like coverity is not following memccpy correctly. Is my understanding correct?
If yes, how can I annotate the abobe code to suppress the false coverity error?
Thank you very much in advance.